# Spark Streaming From Kafka and Write to HDFS in Avro Format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, avro

I basically want to consumes data from Kafka and  write it to HDFS. But happens so is that it is not writing any files in hdfs. it create empty files.

And also please guide me if i want to write in avro format in hdfs how can i modify the code.

For the sake of simplicity am writing to local C drive.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import 
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

object KafkaStreaming extends App{
val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("kafka-streaming")
val conext = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conext, org.apache.spark.streaming.Milliseconds(1))
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "group",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean))
val topics = Array("topic")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
val lines = stream.map(_.value)
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("C:/data/spark/")
})
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()}
```

And below is the build.sbt

```
name := "spark-streaming"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-
10_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.1"
```

Comment: All it required was a filter to check if the batch is empty.. 

    stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(rdd => {

    rdd.foreach(println)
    if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
      rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:/data/spark/")
    }

    })

But i still face issue that the new batch overwrites the old data. i want all data to be appended in the file..

Comment: Even I get the same issue . Did you get it solved?

Comment: Yes , refer https://github.com/Viyaan/spark-kafka-hdfs

Comment: I tried your code but it saves the data in multiple files. I want it to be appended in a single text file.

Answer (score 1):

> Not writing any files in hdfs. it create empty files.

Please check how to debug here

[Unable to see messages from Kafka Stream in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502269/unable-to-see-messages-from-kafka-stream-in-spark/46507732#46507732)

> please guide me if i want to write in avro format in hdfs

https://github.com/sryza/simplesparkavroapp

```
package com.cloudera.sparkavro

import org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
import org.apache.avro.mapreduce.{AvroJob, AvroKeyOutputFormat}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object SparkSpecificAvroWriter {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val outPath = args(0)

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Avro")
    MyKryoRegistrator.register(sparkConf)
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val user1 = new User("Alyssa", 256, null)
    val user2 = new User("Ben", 7, "red")

    val records = sc.parallelize(Array(user1, user2))
    val withValues = records.map((x) => (new AvroKey(x), NullWritable.get))

    val conf = new Job()
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(outPath))
    val schema = User.SCHEMA$
    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(conf, schema)
    conf.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[User]])
    withValues.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf.getConfiguration)
  }
}
```

Comment: Messages are there in Kafka, the problem was when a new batch comes it overwrites the existing data. Now i added filter for empty batches. so now my part files are not empty anymore.. But when it retrives a new batch it overrides the old content.  Can you help me how to append files. for reference  my code in git hub:                              https://github.com/Viyaan/spark-kafka-hdfs/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/spark/streaming/KafkaStreaming.scala

Comment: Try using kafdrop for checking the kafka messages. That may help you debug it from Kafka's end.

Answer (score 1):

Saw your code, you can simply append current timestamp to the files you are writing.

That should solve your problem. :)

==========

If you want to append all the files into one file, then you can use dataframes as below:

I would not recommend using append in HDFS because of the way this Filesystem is designed. But here is what you can try.

1. Create a dataframe from your RDD
2. Use the Dataframe's save mode as ("append") and then write the file.

e.g:

val dataframe = youRdd.toDF();
dataframe.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format(FILE_FORMAT)..save(path);

See if that helps

Comment: Yes but that will create many files, i want only one file. thanks for suggestion thou

Comment: Have updated the answer above. See if that helps your usecase

Answer (score 0):

Before running your Kafka consumer application below **point** you have to check:

- check data is available in Kafka or not
- change `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`
     Here the earliest means kafka automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset.
- Start Kafka console producer application and start typing some messages. Then start your Kafka consumer code, again type some messages on Kafka console producer, then check if messages are printing to consumer console.

You can write the output in avro format using below line of code

```
spark.write.avro("<path>")
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Thank you yes kafka was running and messages were in kafka,. Thanks for your inputs for avro

Answer (score 0):

change this from
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",

to

"auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",