# How to store spark streaming data to Hdfs in Hortonworks?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, spark-streaming, hortonworks-sandbox

I have streamed data from Kafka topics using Spark. This is the code that I have tried. Here I was just displaying the streaming data in console. I want to store this data as a text file in HDFS.

```
import _root_.kafka.serializer.DefaultDecoder
import _root_.kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
object StreamingDataNew {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka").setMaster("local[*]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
val kafkaConf = Map(
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092",
      "zookeeper.connect" -> "localhost:2181",
      "group.id" -> "kafka-streaming-example",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "200000"
    )
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc,
      kafkaConf,
      Map("topic-one" -> 1), // subscripe to topic and partition 1
      StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
    )
    println("printing" + lines.toString())
    val words = lines.flatMap { case (x, y) => y.split(" ") }
    words.print()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

I found that we can write the DStream using 'saveAsTextFiles'.But can someone clearly mention the steps on how to connect with Hortonworks and store in HDFS using the above scala code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Streaming From Kafka and Write to HDFS in Avro Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629618/spark-streaming-from-kafka-and-write-to-hdfs-in-avro-format)

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman Thanks.

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I have tried the possible solutions in the above question link that you share. That didn't work out for me.

Comment: Simply saying "that dint work for me" won't help us much. Can you please tell what issue you are facing?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I have tried out saving the data streamed as text files in local drive .  stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(
  rdd => {
    rdd.foreach(println)
    if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
      rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:/data/spark/") } })
File formats are in crc format. Also files for the total number of partitions have come but I am not able to view the streaming content.

Comment: CRCs are there for checksum. `rdd.foreach(println)` doesn't show anything?

Comment: @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman I can see the messages when I try to open the file. But the problem is ,  am getting new files for each partition.

Comment: That's how Spark works, if you want fewer files, you can repartition (based on required parallelism)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer,
This code worked out for me.

```
package com.spark.streaming

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent

object MessageStreaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Message streaming")

    val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("kafka-streaming")
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(context, org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds(10))
    val kafkaParams = Map(
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka.kafka-cluster.com:9092",
      "group.id" -> "kafka-streaming-example",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "200000"
    )
    val topics = Array("cdc-classic")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))

    val content = stream.filter(x => x.value() != null)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(context)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    stream.map(_.value).foreachRDD(rdd => {

      rdd.foreach(println)
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
     rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).json("hdfs://dev1a/user/hg5tv0/hadoop/MessagesFromKafka")


      }

    })
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination

}}
```